# php merging or concatenation strings when assigning a variable

Tags: php

PHP NOOB, i have been working on this code all day, but cant find any good way to fix it.

here is my code:

```
$priv = explode(',', '0,1,1');
$m = 'me';
for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++)
{
    if($priv[$i] == '0')
    {
        $m.$i = 20;
    }
    else
    {
        $m.$i = 10;
    }
}
```

Am trying to join `$m.$i` together and set it to 20 or 10, but i end up having `me20` or `me10` instead of `me1 = 20` or `me1 = 10` when i echo `$m.$i` which is legit, is there anyways to make this work?

Comment: `when i echo $k.$m which is legit` Where is `$k`?

Comment: Ahh, its okay and now I think you meant `me0 = 20` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$m.$i = 20;`

This will assign `$i = 20` and then concatenate it with `$m` and hence you will see `me20`.

What you need is `$m . $i .= 20;` instead. which will concatenate them altogether.

**Fixed:**

```
<?php

    $priv = explode(',', '0,1,1');
    $m = 'me';
    for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++)
    {
        if($priv[$i] == '0')
        {
          echo  $m . $i .= 20;
        }
        else
        {
         echo   $m.$i .= 10;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

**EDIT:**

The above answer was a total misunderstanding, I realised you intended to create the variables:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++)
{
    if($priv[$i] == '0')
    {
        ${$m.$i} = 20;
        echo $me0;
   }
    else
    {
        ${$m.$i} = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want $m0 = 20 or $m0 = 10

Comment: @ChrysUgwu Ahh Crap.. I just realized. fixing it in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Assign it like so.

```
${$m.$i} = 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to dynamically create variables, so you have to do something like this:

```
$priv = explode(',', '0,1,1');
$m = 'me';
for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++)
{
    if($priv[$i] == '0')
    {
        ${$m.$i} = 20;
    }
    else
    {
        ${$m.$i} = 10;
    }
}
```

then try to priny $me0, $me1